# Neo4j: Ubuntu hosted endpoint protection on Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I am trying to host the neo4j server on an **Azure Ubuntu VM** and opened up the endpoint to enable access from my machine so that I can access the webadmin portal and also debug Asp.net portal code from my machine.

I am however unable to understand how to password protect the access to neo4j endpoint on that VM so that its not open for everyone on the net. looking for at least a simple protection like:

`http://<user>:<pass>@myneo4j.cloudapp.net:7474/db/data`

Is there any guide on how to setup the neo4j on the Azure cloud that I can refer to.

I found [authentication-extension](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/authentication-extension) but unable to understand if this is all i need when setting up connection via Neo4jClient

Regards
Kiran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I downloaded  the right version of '[authentication-extension](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/authentication-extension)' and put it in the plugin folder, it was exactly what i wanted,

added few users and pointed the URI to database as below :

`http(s)://<user>:<pass>@myneo4j.cloudapp.net:7474/db/data`.

and that's all I needed to protect my back end like old fashion SQL server ways.

Comment: Azure Neo4j image is 2.0.1. Where do you find the corresponding version for authentication extension? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ubuntu you can set up nginx as reverse proxy: http://joewhite86.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/secure-neo4j-webadmin-using-http-auth-and-ssl/